# Programmatically created one grouped product associates can be link to other group product?

Tags: grouped-products, magento1.9.2.3

I have created programmatically grouped product now i want to this associates link to other group and this associates products shows as two different product with its qty.Not add one product with adding quantitys as default of magento.